# Net5 calls the external DLL method and the return value is const char*, C# will directly crash

Tags: c#, c++, string, pinvoke

C++ code:

```
__declspec(dllexport) const char* Get() {
    return "hello word!";
}
```

C# code:

```
[DllImport("TestLink.dll")]
public static extern string Get();
```

The program crashes directly after calling

Comment: But there is no problem using IntPtr, I can use the following code to run normally
```
    [DllImport("TestLink.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr Get();
```

Comment: I already see a missing `__stdcall` on the C++ code... And there is at least another problem... The C# will try to free the memory of the C++ string (that must be allocated by `Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem` and not surely a literal string). And you must say to the C# that the string will be ANSI and not Unicode. In the end you are going in the opposite direction of "right".

Comment: internal unsafe static string ConvertToManaged(IntPtr cstr)
        {
            if (IntPtr.Zero == cstr)
            {
                return null;
            }
            return new string((sbyte*)((void*)cstr));
        }
I can use the above code, I see. Net framework seems to be the same conversion

Comment: The "classical" way of returning strings from C++ is using a `StringBuilder()` C#-side. Otherwise there are various solutions

Answer (score 1):

In any case, when you allocate something from C/C++/Native side, you must use the COM allocator which .NET understands. So there are many ways to return a string, for example:

C++:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void* __stdcall GetBSTR() {
    return SysAllocString(L"hello world"); // uses CoTaskMemAlloc underneath
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void* __stdcall GetLPSTR() {

    const char* p = "hello world";
    int size = lstrlenA(p) + 1;
    void* lp = CoTaskMemAlloc(size);
    if (lp)
    {
        CopyMemory(lp, p, size);
    }
    return lp;
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void* __stdcall GetLPWSTR() {

    const wchar_t* p = L"hello world";
    int size = (lstrlenW(p) + 1) * sizeof(wchar_t);
    void* lp = CoTaskMemAlloc(size);
    if (lp)
    {
        CopyMemory(lp, p, size);
    }
    return lp;
}
```

And C#

```
[DllImport("MyDll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
public static extern string GetBSTR();

[DllImport("MyDll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
public static extern string GetLPWSTR();

[DllImport("MyDll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
public static extern string GetLPSTR();
```

Comment: I think you should specify the calling convention... I think the code, as is, is using cdecl C++ side and stdcall C# side. On x64 this probably isn't a big problem because stdcall and cdecl are the same, but on x86 it is.

Comment: @xanatos - yep.

Comment: This is overkill for a const string. Just declare the return type as `IntPtr` and call `Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi()` or `Marshal.PtrToStringUTF8()`.

Comment: Worth pointing out that the reason that the code in the Q fails is because the marshaler calls `CoTaskMemFree` on the pointer returned.